# How to transform data into daily snapshot given the two date columns?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have product data in my table which looks similar to this

| product_id | user_id | sales_start | sales_end | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 15 |
| 2 | 234 | 2022-11-01 | 2022-12-31 | 123 |

I want to transform the table into a daily snapshot so that it would look something like this:

| product_id | user_id | quantity | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 15 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 12 | 15 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1 | 12 | 15 | 2022-01-03 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | 234 | 123 | 2022-12-31 |

I know how to do a similar thing in Pandas, but I need to do it within AWS Athena.
I thought of getting the date interval and unnest it, but I am struggling with mapping them properly.

Any ideas on how to transform data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you `sequence`

```sql
SELECT product_id, user_id, quantity, date(date) as date FROM(    
    VALUES 
    (1, 12, DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-02-01', 15),
    (2, 234, DATE '2022-11-01', DATE '2022-12-31', 123)
) AS t (product_id, user_id, sales_start, sales_end, quantity),
UNNEST(sequence(sales_start, sales_end, interval '1' day)) t(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sequnece`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#id8) to generate dates range and then `unnest` it:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(product_id, user_id, sales_start, sales_end, quantity) as (
    values (1,  12  , date '2022-01-01', date '2022-01-05', 15), -- short date ranges
        (2, 234, date '2022-11-01', date '2022-11-03', 123) -- short date ranges
)

-- query
select product_id, user_id, quantity, date
from dataset,
     unnest(sequence(sales_start, sales_end, interval '1' day)) as t(date);
```

Output:

| product_id | user_id | quantity | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 15 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 12 | 15 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1 | 12 | 15 | 2022-01-03 |
| 1 | 12 | 15 | 2022-01-04 |
| 1 | 12 | 15 | 2022-01-05 |
| 2 | 234 | 123 | 2022-11-01 |
| 2 | 234 | 123 | 2022-11-02 |
| 2 | 234 | 123 | 2022-11-03 |

Comment: It works, but for some reason I get `date` value as a float number instead of a `date` type...?

Comment: Nevermind, it worked when I added `date(date)` as in the suggestion above. Thank you.

Comment: @sowhatnowhuh glad you have figured it out, but this is strange behaviour - changing `date` to `typeof(date)` in final select gives me correct type.

Comment: yes, I know it's a strange behavior, but it probably has to do something with the data types in my case. That table in my question above was an example anyways.